# C# Mongo BsonDocumentBackedClass not working for embedded POCO class

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a two C# POCO's setup as BsonDocumentBackedClass.  Individually they work as expected, if I make one a property of another the property class no longer works and I cannot set any values in it.  Here is an example:

```
[Serializable, DataContract, BsonSerializer(typeof(VehicleStatusClassSerializer))]
public class VehicleStatus : BsonParent, IVehicleStatus
{       
    public VehicleStatus() : this(new BsonDocument()) { }
    internal VehicleStatus(BsonDocument backingDocument) : base(backingDocument, new VehicleStatusClassSerializer()) { }


    [DataMember, BsonElement]
    public String IntelliStatus
    {
        get { return GetValue("IntelliStatus", default(String)); }
        set { SetValue("IntelliStatus", value); }
    }

    [DataMember, BsonElement]
    public String Description
    {
        get { return GetValue("Description", default(String)); }
        set { SetValue("Description", value); }
    }

    [DataMember, BsonElement, BsonSerializer(typeof(GeoLocationVehicleInfoClassSerializer))]
    public GeoLocationVehicleInfo VehicleInfo
    {
        get { return GetValue<GeoLocationVehicleInfo>("VehicleInfo", null);     }
        set { SetValue("VehicleInfo", value); }
    }
```

**The serializer looks like this**

```
public class VehicleStatusClassSerializer : BsonDocumentBackedClassSerializer<VehicleStatus>
{
    public VehicleStatusClassSerializer()
    {       
        RegisterMember("IntelliStatus", "IntelliStatus", new StringSerializer());
        RegisterMember("Description", "Description", new StringSerializer());       
        RegisterMember("VehicleInfo", "VehicleInfo", new GeoLocationVehicleInfoClassSerializer());
    }

    protected override VehicleStatus CreateInstance(BsonDocument backingDocument)
    {
        return new VehicleStatus(backingDocument);
    }
}
```

**The embedded class looks like this**

```
[Serializable, DataContract, BsonSerializer(typeof(GeoLocationVehicleInfoClassSerializer))]
public class GeoLocationVehicleInfo : BsonDocumentBackedClass//, IGeoLocationVehicleInfo
{
    public GeoLocationVehicleInfo() : this(new BsonDocument()) { }
    internal GeoLocationVehicleInfo(BsonDocument backingDocument) : base(backingDocument, new GeoLocationClassSerializer())
    {
    }

    [DataMember, BsonElement]
    public Double speed {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return GetValue<Double>("speed", 0.0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0.0;
            }
        }
        set { SetValue("speed", value); }
    }       
}
```

**And here is the embedded documents serializer**

```
public class GeoLocationVehicleInfoClassSerializer : BsonDocumentBackedClassSerializer<GeoLocationVehicleInfo>
{       
    public GeoLocationVehicleInfoClassSerializer()
    {
        RegisterMember("speed", "speed", new BsonDoubleSerializer());
    }

    protected override GeoLocationVehicleInfo CreateInstance(BsonDocument backingDocument)
    {
        return new GeoLocationVehicleInfo(backingDocument);
    }
}
```

So in the C# code if I try and do VehicleStatus.VehicleInfo.speed = 1.0.  It never gets set.